# Executing "ps" via Runtime exec outputs a lot of data

Tags: java, shell, runtime, runtime.exec, ps

As far as I know running

```
ps
```

with no args in a shell would give me all other processes's started by that shell. However If I run a java jar with a

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("ps");
```

The output of the command is almost evry process in my system. How do I get only processes's started by the shell that started the jar?